# How to use or in pandas and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So, I'm building a model and trying to use | for a new column and I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong. It's supposed to make a new column and type 1 when the value is true.

---

For example, this worked :

`feature_matrix["After 2016"] = (feature_matrix.index.year > 2016).astype(int)`

However this does nothing :

`feature_matrix["Summer"] = (feature_matrix.index.month == 6|7|8|9).astype(int)`

Same thing goes for this when I try to do the weekend using the same method.

---

I tried solving it using :

`feature_matrix["Summer"] = (feature_matrix.index.month == 6| feature_matrix.index.month == 7).astype(int)`

But that gives me : **unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'Int64Index'**

Comment: Try using parenthesis:
feature_matrix["Summer"] = ( (feature_matrix.index.month == 6) | (feature_matrix.index.month == 7) ).astype(int)

Comment: That actually solved it. I'm tired I guess. I usually would have noticed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `isin`

```
(feature_matrix.index.month.isin([6,7,8,9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoben's answer is correct and complete, but a note: `6|7|8\9` is always true, and unless you have True in your column, this will do nothing.